# Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'upload' error after migrating

Tags: swift

After migrating to 5.0 receive this error - > `Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'upload'`

Changing `Alamofire` to `AF` doesn't help.

Can't run build in xcode due to this error.

```
Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                formData.forEach({ (key, value) in
                    guard let valueData = "\(value)".data(using: .utf8) else {
                        return
                    }
                    
                    multipartFormData.append(valueData, withName: key)
                })
                
                switch uploadOption {
                    
                case .data(let data, let meta):
                    multipartFormData.append(
                        data,
                        withName: "file",
                        fileName: meta.fileName,
                        mimeType: meta.mimeType
                    )
                    
                case .stream(let stream, let length, let meta):
                    multipartFormData.append(
                        stream,
                        withLength: length,
                        name: "file",
                        fileName: meta.fileName,
                        mimeType: meta.mimeType
                    )
                }
        },
            to: url,
            encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) in
                switch encodingResult {
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.failure(error: error))
                    
                case .success(let request, _, _):
                    cancelable.request = request
                    
                    request.responseData(completionHandler: { (response) in
                        if let error = response.error {
                            completion(.failure(error: error))
                            return
                        }
                        
                        completion(.success)
                    })
                }
                
        })
```

Comment: Please check the documentation for upload [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-data-to-a-server).

Comment: @Kamran Thank you so much! I found my problem, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I have Alamofire version 5.2, it seems ok,
some syntax changed after you migrate to 5.x,
plz check it or update it to 5.2

[image]